# React Native scroll bar in the middle of the screen

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-scrollview

**Hermes enabled**

**OS: iOS**

**getting with FlatList and ScrollView**

When developing ScrollView or FlatList, having no issues with the scroll bar. In production, sometimes it looks ugly and positions at the middle of the screen, sometimes with huge/small offset from the right side (where it should be), sometimes even on the left side.
Here is the image of what I am getting:

[image]

Thank you mates in advance!

Comment: We noticed this specifically when the user has set a non-default font size on their device.

Answer (score 10):

Try adding `scrollIndicatorInsets={{ right: 1 }}` to ScrollView

Comment: I try this, but sometimes solve, sometimes still occur

Answer (score 2):

For my instance of this bug, it was caused by conditionally rendering a FlatList. My pseudo-code was:

```
if (initialLoading) return <FullScreenLoadingPage/>

else return <FlatList data={...} />
```

When I re-worked this to:

```
return (
  <FlatList 
    data={...} 
    ListEmptyState={initialLoading ? FullScreenLoadingPage : ...} 
  />
)
```

The problem went away.

Comment: This was my issue as well. For reference, I was able to replicate this particular bug after slowing down animations in simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `scrollIndicatorInsets={{ right: 1 }}` within FlatList properties worked fine for me

- currently using react-native 0.68.2